# Spring-boot Api endpoint for uploading file not working after adding 'spring-boot-starter-hateoas' dependency

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-hateoas

I have a simple API function to upload a file similar to:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/documents",
             consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> uploadDocument(@RequestPart Mono<FilePart> file){
    
    return storeDocumentService
                    .upload(file)
                    .map(fileLocation->ResponseEntity.ok(fileLocation))
}
```

The code works ok and uploads the file. The problem comes when I want to make the response a bit better by returning the link to the uploaded file. For this I want to use HATEOAS 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'. As soon as I add the dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas' to my 'build.gradle' the endpoint stops working and I get a response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-02-20T04:28:10.620+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/documents"
}
```

and also I get in the logs:

```
2023-02-20T05:28:10.618+01:00  WARN 2993 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/pdf' is not supported]
```

It is important to point out that I upload a ".pdf" file with a header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data". And most important the only change in the working code and not working code is that i just add the dependency for HATEOAS 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'

Answer (score 0):

For Uploading File We can easily use the type MultiPartFile , This will handles all the types of files and we can easily retrive the fileInputStream(data) from it.
The following code may helps you!..

```
@PostMapping("uploadExcelData")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadExcelData(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    List<...> dataList = fileHandling.convertFileAsJson(file);
    if (!dataList.isEmpty()) {
        return ....
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("No Records found !!");
    }
}
```

I hope the above code will helps you to handle the File in the Endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question was about HATEOAS, but I thinking it is a webflux problem. I'm using webflux and I think MultipartFile file is not working with webflux, also I think that the org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas has also problems with webflux when using  FilePart in the endpoint.